# Format error with sprintf to create file name buffer

Tags: c

I am using `sprintf` to format a file name buffer, but clang-10 reports:

> warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char
> *' [-Wformat]   sprintf(file_name_buffer, "%c", file_name);

This is the code:

```
char file_name[ ] = "/path/filename.bin";
int file_name_len = sizeof(file_name);
char file_name_buffer[file_name_len];
sprintf(file_name_buffer, "%c", file_name);
outfile = fopen(file_name_buffer, "wb+");
```

I thought `%c` is the format string for a char string.  How do I format this for `sprintf` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%c` is for a **single** `char` and `%s` is for strings.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char file_name[] = "/path/filename.bin";
    int file_name_len = sizeof(file_name);
    char file_name_buffer[file_name_len];

    sprintf(file_name_buffer, "%s", file_name);
//                             ^^

    FILE *outfile = fopen(file_name_buffer, "wb+");
    if(outfile) {
        // success
    } else {
        // failure
    }
}
```

In this case, you may want to use `strncpy` instead of `sprintf` though since there's not much of formatting going on in your `sprintf`.

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strncpy(file_name_buffer, file_name, sizeof file_name_buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ted Lyngmo -- that's the answer.  SO says I have to wait 6 minutes to accept this as best answer.